# Mistake in Discriminants, Resultants, and Multidimensional Determinants?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

I'm studying this proof in the book cited in the title.

[image]
[image]

The author say that any multiplicative function $\chi\colon\mathsf{GL}(k)\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}^\times$ is a power of the determinant. But what if I take $\chi(g)=\overline{\det g}$? Is this a mistake? If not and I'm missing something where can I find a proof of this fact?

Comment: The function $f$ is polynomial, and we can fix a generic $M$ and define $\chi(g)=f(gM)f(M)^{-1}$, so $\chi$ is also a polynomial  function.  Any character that is a polynomial function is a power of the determinant.

Comment: A more pathological multiplicative function is $\chi(g) = \exp f(\log |\det g|)$, where $f$ is any solution to Cauchy's functional equation, and we further define $\chi(g) = 0$ whenever $g$ is singular.

Comment: @NeilStrickland many thanks for the helpfull remark. Can you give me a rference where I can find your claim? I know almost nothing about Rep. Theory.

Comment: I'm sure it goes back much earlier than that, but a natural source for polynomial representations of $\mathrm{GL}(n)$ (the 1-dimensional ones being those @NeilStrickland describes) is [Green - Polynomial representations of $\mathrm{GL}(n)$](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2FBFb0092296).

Comment: This is not a mistake, in this book they consider algebraic geometry, and hence consider only \textbf{polynomial} (i.e. regular) functions. The complex conjugate of a polynomial function is anti-holomorphic and hence not a "function" in 
Gelfand-Kapranov-Zelevinski context.